# Preload UISearchBar Display Results on click + Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am working with SearchBar on iOS 7. In my ViewController, I have written this code in `viewDidLoad()`

```
searchDisplay = UISearchDisplayController(searchBar: self.searchBar, contentsController: self)
searchDisplay?.searchResultsDataSource = self
searchDisplay?.searchResultsDelegate = self
```

When I click the search text field, the view is changed and this is what I see

[image]

Only when I start typing, I see rows as shown below:

[image]

**Question: I want to preload search results when I first click the search text field. How can I do that?**

- I don't want to pass `" "`. This would pre-load the search results, but when user presses back button, the view is like Image 1
- Is there a way to override the search bar. If yes, then can someone guide me how to proceed further. **I am looking for guidance & not the exact code.**

Debugging shows datasource methods are called thrice, but nothing is displayed on clicking search bar text field

I am using iOS 7 and Xcode 7. Kindly help where I am wrong...

Comment: In which function do you call your "updateSearch" code?

Comment: For now its hardcoded in the number of rows and item at index path

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to do exactly but here are to ways your question could maybe be answered:

**First:**

This Function is called when the user clicks on the searchBar. You could use it to edit the searchBar itself to start searching with a different one or you call self.tableView.reloadData():

```
   func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool{

}
```

**Second:**

return an empty UITableViewCell if the searchText = "" to have  row in the tableView:

```
    if searchBar.text == ""{
return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: Did you try the code you provided, because it doesn't work